# Hazelcast lock doesn't provide synchronization

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I'm trying to acheive method synchronization in Hazelcast, but it doesn't seem to work even on a single cluster.

I'm using a simple Hazelcast config

```
@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfig {
    @Bean
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(){
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }
}
```

There's a sample service, that generates some ID, using timestamp. It's supposed to be unique, so I'm using lock, provided by Hazelcast

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    public Long generateVersion(){
        ILock lock = hazelcastInstance.getLock("version_key");
        try{
            lock.lock();
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not generate version ", ex);
            throw ex;
        } finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Test checks, that there were no duplicates generated.

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    List<Long> versions = new ArrayList();
    Collection<Callable<Long>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    int nThreads = 100;
    for(int i=0; i<nThreads; i++){
        tasks.add(new Callable<Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long call() throws Exception {
                return myService.generateVersion();
            }
        });
    }
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    List<Future<Long>> results = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
    for(Future<Long> result : results){
        Long pingResult = result.get();
        if (!versions.contains(pingResult))
            versions.add(pingResult);
        else
            throw new AssertionError("Found duplicate "+ pingResult);
    }
}
```

However, I get a lot of duplicates while I run the test. Test is run on a single node (I plan to run it on a cluster environment afterwards).

Is hazelcast providing synchronization on a single cluster node? Or have I misconfigured it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.getTimestamp()` might not be unique. You can call it twice and get the same result.

You could get Hazelcast to generate the id for you https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.10.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/flakeidgen/FlakeIdGenerator.html

Comment: Why is getTimestamp not unique, if it's surronded by lock? Does it mean that lock/unlock hazelcast process takes less that 1msc? I thought that process of lock/unlock takes enough time.

Comment: @Ermintar changes to the local HazelcastInstance are going to be pretty damn fast. Also, System.currentTimeMillis() can be quite coarse-grained (in my experience 10ms is quite common). That means that between ticks you are going to retrieve the same timestamp. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764428/how-to-improve-system-currenttimemillis-granularity